# ubuntu: starting program with sudo on boot

Tags: ubuntu-9.10, startup, process

I am trying to start xampp when the ubuntu starts on ubuntu 9.10. I tried going to system->preferences->startup applications adding it there, but it didn't work. I surmised it was because it needs to be started as root. I know you can make a startup script some how, but I'm not sure how to do it. How can I make it start xampp when the computer boots, even without logging in?

FYI, the command for starting it is `sudo /opt/lampp/lampp start`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to add it to the startup scripts.  This may help http://www.apachefriends.org/en/faq-xampp-linux.html#fsl

Comment: it says to do `egrep :initdefault: /etc/inittab` but when i do that it says no such file or directory

Comment: I tried adding the things to init.d and restarted the server, but it still didn't start.

Comment: according to http://embraceubuntu.com/2005/09/07/adding-a-startup-script-to-be-run-at-bootup/, you can't just add a script to the init.d directory.

$ chmod +x SCRIPT_NAME
$ update-rc.d SCRIPT_NAME defaults